# Model driven interceptor not working as expected

Tags: java, jsp, security, struts2

Model driven interceptor is not working properly.

Action class :

```
     public class CampusManagerEditAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<RegistrationForm>
          
    {
       RegistrationForm registrationForm = new RegistrationForm();
        public RegistrationForm getModel(){return registrationForm;}
        public String execute(){
            //incoming request is coming from Hyperlink and I pass one variable in that url
          sysot(regisForm.getId());//Working fine
           registrationFrom = DaoLayer.getFormObject(id);
           //I can see the data here.tooo
       }
      }
```

I call action from an anchor link in link I pass `id` which I can retrieve from from as `from.getId()` but when I try to commit response with new values of form those Form values are not visible in my jsp

**JSP page*

```
      <s:property value="class"/>
```

I tried `<s:property value="%{registrationForm.class}"/>` also
but not working.

**Struts.xml**

```
      <action name="campusManagerEditLink"  class="com.brainybunch.campusmanager.status.action.CampusManagerEditAction" >           
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"></interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"></interceptor-ref>   
         <result name="success">/editCampusManagerStudentReport.jsp</result> 
    </action>
```

If you want me to post my libraries I can post.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` is a excluded word from OGNL processing which happens in Struts tags. You can read the doc about security mechanizms used in the default implementation of [ExcludedPatternsChecker](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/security/ExcludedPatternsChecker.html).

> Used across different interceptors to check if given string matches one of the excluded patterns.

---

And generally this method is called

> [isExcluded(java.lang.String)](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/security/ExcludedPatternsChecker.html#isExcluded(java.lang.String))
>
> Checks if value matches any of patterns on exclude list

---

Comment: but when I used `<s:debug/>` tag in resultant jsp, I can see model object state as it was in request state, I think my new form object was not pushed to `value stack`

Comment: But when I did this manual pust I can see form is set with new values `ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().push(model);`